# Help with nautilus not sharing some folder but sharing others

Tags: nautilus

I have an external mounted at /mnt/hdd5 and I have a working share folder in that location called Movies2.
When I try to create one called TVShows3, I get the error in the image. I don't understand since it is sharing 1 folder just fine. Any help is appreciated.

[image]